# Artefact in read/write (copying) video file using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-processing

I am trying to read a video frame by frame and process it and write it back to another video file.

Part of the process is to read the video and in another part write it back into another video. I noted that when I am doing this, I am getting some artifacts on the generated video.

The simplest code that I can show the problem is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string inputFile = "D:\\MyData\\sample2.mp4";
    std::string outputFileName = "D:\\MyData\\sample2out.mp4";

    VideoCapture inputVideo;
    inputVideo.open(inputFile);


    VideoWriter videoWritter;
    videoWritter.open(outputFileName, inputVideo.get(CAP_PROP_FOURCC), inputVideo.get(CAP_PROP_FPS),Size(inputVideo.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), inputVideo.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)));

    while (true) // loop until all frames read. this 
    {
        cv::Mat frame;
        // Capture frame-by-frame
        inputVideo >> frame;
        // If the frame is empty, break immediately
        if (frame.empty())
            break;
        videoWritter << frame;
    }
    inputVideo.release();
    videoWritter.release();

}
```

when I run this code, the output video has some artifacts that can be seen in the following image:

[image]

I also noted that the size of the output file became a lot larger than the original one ( input file ~ 98 Mbyte and output is around 143 Mbyte).

How can I fix this artifact? why the output size is bigger than the input file when the compression and other parameters are set to be the same?

I am using OpenCV 4.6 and Visual studio 2022 on windows 10.

## Edit 1

I run the application on two videos, both of which are downloaded from the internet, one from a site (I can not remember the name of the site but it offers free videos) and the other downloaded from Youtube using a youtube downloader website.

I can share the videos, but I do not know how to upload them to this site. How can I share it?

I can see the same issue in both videos.

If I extract images and save them into a jpeg, the images are correct. but when I encode them into a video I can see the issue.

## Edit 2

Sample files are uploaded here: https://www.filemail.com/d/kobthfbkbjanwqm

Comment: you are doing video compression (encoding). do you realize that? the parameters are __not__ the same. the result file getting larger is due to different compression strength (bitrate/quality).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz How can I fix it? There is no parameter that I can set on VideoWritter to change the compression setting. How can I read the compression setting from the input video and set it on the output video?

Comment: for modern codecs, it is near impossible to re-encode a decoded video and then get the same bitstream (encoding). just forget it. -- that picture you present looks like very severe compression, or corrupted data. -- what is your actual problem? what is the problem you're trying to solve by doing this? https://xyproblem.info/ perhaps you need to learn more about video formats and compression.

Comment: I don't think we can answer the question without `sample2.mp4` file (or part of the file or other file with the same problem). Please share your video file, if you can.

Comment: @mans **(1)** Does this happen with all other MP4 files or just this one (and a few others similar to it)? **(2)** You can use a tool like [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) to compare/check your input and output codec settings. **(3)** Since the original appears fine in other media players, what happens if you use one to grab that frame as PNG or JPG and re-encode into video (_eg:_ 5 seconds of a still image), does the MP4 picture quality now match the input?

Comment: @Rotem I can share the file, but I don't know how to upload it to StackOverflow.  Can you please help me to share the video?

Comment: @VC.One Please see my edit above. How can I read video codec information in C++? I can use MediaInfo for this task, but I also like to learn how to do this in C++.

Comment: Find a way to share the file - use File Dropper or share it using Google Drive. As far as I know, Google Drive sharing by link doesn't expose your email.

Comment: @Rotem Sample input and output are uploaded via a file upload system. Please see the updated question.

Comment: The issue is not reproducible (I tested with Python, not with C++). You are encoding H.264 video with `fourcc` = `avc1`. H.264 decoding is natively supported by OpenCV, but H.264 encoding requires additional DLL. I had to download `openh264-1.8.0-win64.dll` from [here](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/releases/tag/v1.8.0). For testing, I copied the dll to `c:\Windows\System32\`. The output video file size is almost 1GBytes (but there are no artifacts).

Comment: both files play fine here. did you use a broken video player program? voting to close, issue is not reproducible.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Did you used the output file that I uploaded or you generate one?